# log base 2 and nan

Tags: java, math

I use the code below to calculate log base 2.

```
Math.log(x)/Math.log(2);
```

With this function, i get nan if x=4/5.

With calc, excel this problem don't exist.

How to avoid to get nan and get the real value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a strong feeling that your `4/5` is integers. Which would mean that `4/5` will evaluate to `0` due to integer division.

`log(0)` is negative infinity, that could be the source of your `NaN`.

To fix this, cast your numbers to floating-point before you do the division:

```
double x = (double)4 / 5;
```

Answer (score 6):

I suspect your problem is because `4 / 5` is `0`, because it does the division using integer arithmetic.  If you want to use floating point arithmetic to get `0.8`, then you should try `4.0 / 5`.